# Why do we have String class, if StringBuilder or StringBuffer can do what a String does?

Tags: java, c#

I've always wondered why does JAVA and C# has `String` (immutable & threadsafe) class, if they have `StringBuilder` (mutable & not threadsafe) or `StringBuffer` (mutable & threadsafe) class. Isn't `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` superset of `String` class? I mean, why should I use `String` class, if I've option of using `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`?

For example, Instead of using following,

```
String str;
```

Why can't I always use following?

```
StringBuilder strb; //or
StringBuffer strbu;
```

In short, my question is, How will my code get effected if I replace `String` with `StringBuffer` class? Also, `StringBuffer` has added advantage of mutability.

Comment: In some situation it is beneficiary to use string instead of stringbuilder. remember string is flyweight. I am just finding some link that can provide you with proof.

Comment: What do you mean by flyweight?

Comment: Hah? String is used in so many ways and it is good to have this immutable class. StringBuilder and -Buffer are used to create/build Strings - why should they be used to *replace* Strings? I don't get it why you don't get it!

Comment: @Abhishek look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). String's interning nature makes it more proficient.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Got it. So, `String` will make only one copy for every distinct string literal. That could be a problem, I mean what happens if string pool if filled?

Comment: @Abhishek You are right that could be a problem but in more scenarios that is beneficiary. Look at [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30350176/1505865) below.

Comment: As they aren't supersets, your question is based on a false premiss.

Answer (score 16):

> I mean, why should I use String class, if I've option of using StringBuilder/StringBuffer?

Precisely because it's immutable. Immutability has a whole *host* of benefits, primarily that it makes it much easier to reason about your code without creating copies of the data everywhere "just in case" something decides to mutate the value. For example:

```
private readonly String name;

public Person(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) // Or whatever
    {
        // Throw some exception
    }
    this.name = name;
}

// All the rest of the code can rely on name being a non-null 
// reference to a non-empty string. Nothing can mutate it, leaving
// evil reflection aside.
```

Immutability makes sharing simple and efficient. That's particularly useful for multi-threaded code. It makes "modifying" (i.e. creating a new instance with different data) more painful, but in many situations that's absolutely fine, because values pass through the system without ever being modified.

Immutability is *particularly* useful for "simple" types such as strings, dates, numbers (`BigDecimal`, `BigInteger` etc). It allows them to be used within maps more easily, it allows a simple equality definition, etc.

Comment: I can replace `private readonly String name;` with `private readonly StringBuffer name;`, isn't it? How will it effect my code? I mean, I get desired result with `StringBuffer` and added advantage of mutability. So, why should I use `String`?

Comment: @Abhishek: "and added advantage of mutability" - no, that's a *disadvantage*. It would mean someone could call `Person p = new Person(builder);` with a builder which *initially* passes my validation criteria - and then modify it afterwards, without the `Person` class having any say in it. In order to avoid that, the `Person` class would need to copy the validated data. Mutability is a huge *problem*, not an advantage. The key to software design is managing complexity - and widescale mutability is a massive enemy of that.

Comment: If immutability was only an advantage, we would no longer see imperative code like Java or C# but only see functional languages. If mutability was only an advantage, we would not see functional languages at all. As both of them are quite popular, neither is the case.

Comment: @Georg: Right, which is why I talk about it making modification more painful. But for some types (such as `String`) the benefits of immutability far outweight the downsides for most uses. I'd argue that `java.util.Date` and several similar classes should *also* be immutable...

Comment: @JonSkeet I totally agree. It is a bit like the Haskell-programmers replacing the entire house to change the light-bulb. For strings and a lot of other types like Date, this is reasonable unless the strings get too long. In fact, the fact that the Date type is immutable in .NET supports this argumentation.

Comment: Don't forget that immutability makes using String values as keys in maps a whole lot more sensible....

Comment: @JonSkeet I can use `StringBuffer` for `Person p = new Person(buffer);` and it will be thread safe. So, it wouldn't matter in that scenario, right?

Comment: @Abhishek: Threading is only one part of the benefit. I could still write `buffer.setLength(0)` afterwards, leaving an invalid `Person` object despite it having been valid at construction time. No need for multiple threads.

Comment: @JonSkeet then it would be bad coding, isn't it? I mean if I'm using single thread then I wouldn't do it. If I do it, it would be a bug on my part.

Comment: @Abhishek: Yes, it would be a bug - but one that was really easy to introduce, due to mutability. It's hard to keep it clear what can be mutated and what can't - so you end up either copying things everywhere, or never *actually* mutating things even though the compiler doesn't stop you. That doesn't sound like a good thing to me.

Comment: @Abhishek It would matter, of course, in the example in particular because the name is readonly. Then `string` would not allow any changes whereas `StringBuffer` does. Even if name was not readonly, the change has a great impact (also see my answer for details).

Comment: @JonSkeet So, is it just a programming paradigm and help programmers to debug code easily?

Comment: @Abhishek: It's an approach which allows programmers to manage complexity, making it easier to reason about their code. That goes a long way beyond debugging.

Comment: @JonSkeet Understood. Thanks for helping me out. One more question, so `String` objects will perform better than `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` objects in any scenario? :)

Comment: @Abhishek: That's too vague a question to answer. Being immutable allows strings to be shared with just a copy of the reference... So at the very least, scenarios where multiple classes want to be assured that their data doesn't change but they want to share values will work better with strings... Does that count in your view?

Answer (score 3):

1) `StringBuilder` as well as `StringBuffer` both are `mutable`. So it will cause a few problems like using in collections like keys in `hashMap`. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342859/why-are-immutable-objects-in-hashmaps-so-effective).

Another example of advantage of immutability will be what `Jon` has mentioned in his comments. I am just pasting here.

> Someone can call `Person p = new Person(builder);` with a builder which initially passes my validation criteria - and then modify it afterwards, without the Person class having any say in it. In order to avoid that, the Person class would need to copy the validated data.

Immutabilty assures this does not happen.

2) As `string` is most extensively used object in java, the `string pool` offers to resuse same string, thus saving memory.

Comment: I can use `StringBuffer`, if thread safety is the issue. How does String help in reuse of memory? I mean `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` objects are also stored in memory location, which can be reused.

Comment: @Abhishek You wil need to write a specific function that searches the memory and returns the string for you, now suppose at some places string got changed, all the instances using it will change, which might not be the requirement. Here again comes `immutability` of string useful. This is the biggest factor

Comment: I'll use `StringBuffer` (thread-safety), so I don't have to worry about somebody changing data.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) that immutability is one reason to use `String`. Another reason (from a C# perspective) is that `String` is actually lighter weight than `StringBuilder`. If you look at reference source for both [String](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c) and [String Builder](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,adf60ee46ebd299f) you will see that `StringBuilder` actually has a number of `String` constants in it. As a developer, you should only use what you need so unless you need the added benefits provided from `StringBuilder` you should use `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers have already outlined that there are shortcomings from using mutable variants such as `StringBuilder`. To illustrate the problem, one thing that you cannot achieve with `StringBuilder` is associative memory, i.e. hash tables. Sure, most implementations will allow you to use `StringBuilder` as a key for hashtables, but they will only find the values for the exact same instance of `StringBuilder`. However, the typical behavior that you would want to achieve is that it does not matter where the string comes from as only the characters are important, as you e.g. reade the string from a database or file (or any other external resource).

However, as far as I understood your question, you were mainly asking about field types. And indeed, I see your point particularly taking into account that we are doing the exact same thing with collections of other objects which are usually not immutable objects but mutable collections, such as `List` or `ArrayList` in C# or Java, respectively. In the end, a string is only a collection of characters, so why not making it mutable?

The answer I would give here is that the usual behavior of how such a string is changed is very different to usual collections. If you have a collection of subsequent elements, it is very common to only add a single element to the collection, leaving most of the collection untouched, i.e. you would not discard a list to insert an item, at least unless you are programming in Haskell :). For many strings like names, this is different as you typically replace the whole string. Given the importance of a string data type, the platforms usually offer a lot of optimization for strings such as interned strings, making the choice even more biased towards strings.

However, in the end, every program is different and you might have requirements that make it more reasonable to use `StringBuilder` by default, but for the given reasons, I think that these cases are rather rare.

*EDIT:* As you were asking for examples. Consider the following code:

```
stopwatch.Start();
var s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    s = "." + s;
}
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

stopwatch.Restart();
var s2 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
     s2.Insert(0, ".");
}
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Technically, both bits are doing a very similar thing, they will insert a character at the first position and shift whatever comes after. Both versions will involve copying the whole string that has been there before. The version with `string` completes in 1750ms on my machine whereas `StringBuilder` took 2245ms. However, both versions are reasonably fast, making the performance impact negligible in this case.

Comment: You said optimization. What kind of optimization you mean? I mean is String better in performance than StringBuffer? How? When is it? Can you share example?

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example.However, I don't know what exactly is done in this optimization.

Comment: However, I just checked, it seems like this is not really an optimization, a dumb list of chars takes about 1000ms.

Comment: Exactly! So, I still don't understand why should I choose `String` over `StringBuffer`. If need, simple append/insert like these I'll go with char array, as you said :)

Comment: Maybe another argument is that as soon as you start doing something with the strings, you will need them as `string` in most applications. If you use `StringBuffer` all along, you will need conversions that are not really memory efficient, but as I said, if you are sure that this is the best for your application, go ahead.

Comment: Yup, I knew that `StringBuffer` implicitly uses `String`. It was one of the reason for my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add some differences between `String` and `StringBuilder` classes:

Yes, as mentioned above `String` is immutable class and content cannot be changed after string has been created. It is allow to work with the same string objects from different threads without locking. 
If you need to concatenate a lot of strings together, use `StringBuilder` class. When you use "+" operator it creates a lot of string objects on managed heap and hurts performance.

`StringBuilder` is mutable class. `StringBuilder` stores characters in array and can manipulate with characters without creating a new string object (such as add, remove, replace, append). 
If you know approximate length of result string you should set capacity. Default capacity is 16 (.NET 4.5). It gives you performance improvements because `StringBuilder` has inner array of chars. Array of chars recreates when count of characters exceeds current capacity.

Answer (score -1):

**`String`**:

- is immutable (so you can use it in collections)
- **every operation creates a new instance on the Heap.** Technically speaking really depends on the code.

**For performance and memory consumption purposes it makes sense to use `StringBuilder`.**

Comment: Not necessarily. Strings literals will be interned when possible.

Comment: As I said depends on the code... Optimizations are not part of the question.

Comment: So why post misinformation about it? But this isn't an optimisation. It is specified in the language that string literals are pooled.